# Using CloudFront to split traffic between origin servers – is this configuration right?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I'm replacing a legacy website with a new one, in stages. From a user perspective, all existing URLs must remain the same, but certain paths should serve new pages.

I have two origin servers: the legacy one (`www.mysite.com`) and the new, EC2 one (`www.ec2-loadbalancer.com`) – obviously mock URLs for privacy reasons.

I've created an AWS CloudFront distribution with a CNAME setting of `www.mysite.com`. Within this distribution I've created two origins domains:

- `www.mysite.com`
- `www.ec2-loadbalancer.com`

Within CloudFront I've configured some behaviours so that paths like `/foo` are sent to my EC2 load balancer origin, and all other paths (eg. default) are sent to `www.mysite.com`.

From a DNS perspective, I've added a `CNAME` record of `www.mysite.com` which points to my Cloudfront host domain (eg. `foo.cloudfront.net.`). The `A` record for this domain points to the IP of the legacy server.

I launched all of this today and it seems to have worked, but I'm seeing intermittent 403 errors on the site, and two hours after making the change (there was no "www" `CNAME` before, so TTL shouldn't make a difference), some browsers are still serving the site from the original IP (rather than the CloudFront one).

Have I configured this properly? I couldn't work out how to do this via the `A` record – that points to the IP of the legacy server, and CloudFront doesn't allow me to enter an IP address as an origin. Should I have pointed the `www` CNAME at the IP address, made the `A` record point at CloudFront instead? I'm a bit lost here.

On the other hand, it could all be a propagation thing, but I'm wary having seen 40x errors hours after making the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame you can't share the domains with us to help debugging, but at the very least, [`dig`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/dig-command-examples) is your friend. For instance:

```
$ dig membership.theguardian.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
membership.theguardian.com. 367 IN  CNAME   i.global-ssl.fastly.net.
i.global-ssl.fastly.net. 12 IN  A   151.101.128.67
i.global-ssl.fastly.net. 12 IN  A   151.101.64.67
i.global-ssl.fastly.net. 12 IN  A   151.101.0.67
i.global-ssl.fastly.net. 12 IN  A   151.101.192.67
```

...tells you that `membership.theguardian.com` is pointing to Fastly by CNAME. You can check with alternate DNS servers, like [Google's DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) on 8.8.8.8, by doing this:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 membership.theguardian.com
```

...so you can see how other people are resolving your domains.

> From a DNS perspective, I've added a CNAME record of www.mysite.com
>   which points to my Cloudfront host domain (eg. foo.cloudfront.net.).
>   The A record for this domain points to the IP of the legacy server.

I'm *not* a DNS expert, so it's possible I'm not understanding you here, but this sound like it introduces ambiguity? To me this sounds like you have two different records for the same `www.mysite.com` domain, one of which points to CloudFront, and the other to the IP of your legacy server. Depending on how that gets resolved a browser could be sent to one or the other?!

- `www.mysite.com` should point **only** to CloudFront. I would personally just use a CNAME for this.
- You should have unambiguous addresses for both your legacy server and your EC2 Elastic Load Balancer - I would personally give them their own clear domain names, to avoid confusion (eg. `legacy.mysite.com` & `beta.mysite.com`) - and in CloudFront refer to only to those clear names when you're directing traffic (eg. passing traffic on to `www.mysite.com` as a way of going to the legacy server would be confusing).

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: This was the solution. I removed the `A` record and pointed the `www` CNAME at Cloudfront. I think the ambiguity between those two records was the cause here as there are no 40x/50x errors any more. Thanks Roberto!

Answer (score 2):

i think you should create an A record (for the named domain name) with an alias pointing to the cloudfront distribution. It should solve the problem.

i.e. Use Alias name instead of IP address and point your domain to cloudfront:

[image]

Comment: Where are you suggesting the A record should point? Somewhere in this setup I need to reference the IP address of the legacy server...

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Using alias name, you won't need to reference the IP address of the server

Comment: Thanks – I'm still not clear and I'm not sure this is right. My domain name isn't hosted on Route 53, but even so, this won't work, surely? If I make an alias record for the CloudFront distribution, then yes, visiting my domain will go there, but my origin server won't point to the original IP any more (as the A record for the current domain currently points there), surely?